# observable issue on iOS 7

Tags: knockout.js

I've discovered this issue today and thought I'd post here to see if anyone's had the same problem.

I've written a bar chart engine for knockoutjs and everything is working as expected except for on the iPad with IOS7.

The issue seems to be related to the number of times we access an observable on each bar. At present there are 2 bar charts with the days of the month, each bar having its own observable yAxisValue property.

Each HTML rendering of a bar makes reference to the yAxisValue property 5 times.

So that's roughly 5 * 60 (300) reads per page load.

The issue presents when we try to set the yAxisValue. The script crashes and as it stands we're not in a position to debug it (I need to hook the iPad up to a Mac to do so properly).

Removing the HTML that makes reference to the yAxisValue property and the script stops crashing.

It seems like this is a perf issue of some kind but I'm at a bit of a loss as to where to go next with it.

Older iPads seem to be working just fine. It's just the ones with iOS7 that are having this issue.

Any input welcome.

Comment: Moments after asking this question I solved the problem we were having. I need more information as to why it caused a problem though. The issue turned out to be a custom binding that was looping over the bars collection for each bar. So 30^2 (roughly). It seems that the older iPad just got on with it where as iOS7 failed miserably.

Comment: Maybe the throttle extender can help you improve performance? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html